# Encoding Data in JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, forms

My new code with the updated changes. Clicking the button after inserting a number has no effect on the form.

Front-End

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#go").click(function() {
    var id=$("#myid").val();
    $.getJSON('find.php',{num:id},function(obj){
       alert(obj.toSource());
       $("input.fname").val(obj.FirstName); 
       $("input.sname").val(obj.Surname); 
       $("input.age").val(obj.Age); 

     });
 });
});
```

Form

```
 ID: <input type="text" name="id" class="myid">
 <input type="button" value="Go" id="go" />

 First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="fname"><br>
 Surname: <input type="text" name="Surname" class="sname"><br>
 Age: <input type="text" name="Age" class="age"><br>
```

Back-End

```
 $id = $_GET['num'];

 $result = array('FirstName' => 1, 'Surname' => 2, 'Age' => 3);

 echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: You have not even explained whether there is a problem. What is your current code doing and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Hi, I want the code to take the data found in the selected record and use it to populate the elements in the form i.e. elements named 'fname'/'sname'/'age'. Currently there is no response when an id is entered and no reason in the browsers developer tools.

Comment: @William231: your updated code should work fine. Try navigating to `find.php?num=whatever` yourself and seeing what output the server provides.

Comment: @Matt The output from that is the array I specified in the back end php file --> {"FirstName":1,"Surname":2,"Age":3}

Comment: @William231: Can you check you're getting the same response in your developer tools in the browser you're using? (are you sure it's `find.php` and not `/find.php`?). Check the elements exist on your page with the name you expect; try `alert($('input.fsname,input.sname,input.age').length)` to make sure that gives you 3. Check the JavaScript to launch the JSON request is actually being executed (stick an `alert()` in before).

Comment: Make sure that you have included class name in your html cause your selectors are ("input.fname") that means you have to provide html like this <input type="text" class="fname">. I have checked above updated code and its working perfectly filling up my form.

Comment: @Matt: It's find.php, held in the same directory as the html file. The developer tools don't give me anything on either the front page, or the php back page. I tried your alert and got this message -> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'alert'. Perhaps I used it wrongly? I'm unfamiliar with 'alert'. Any Ideas?

Comment: @Kamal: Here's an example of one of my form fields -> First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="fname"><br>

Comment: @Matt: When I just run find.php through the browser, (i.e. without num=whatever) I get an undefined index error -> Notice: Undefined index: num in *:\****\*********\*********\website\find.php on line 10 {"FirstName":1,"Surname":2,"Age":3}

Comment: @William231: [`alert()` is a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Alerts_and_Notifications#Basic_modal_alert). It looks like you were calling `$.alert(...)`; all you need to have in your console is `alert($('input.fsname,input.sname,input.age').length)`. Also check the JavaScript to launch the JSON request is actually being executed (stick an alert() in before).

Comment: Thanks for your patience. The alert outputs [object Object]. However the other alert(with fname etc) doesnt seem to produce anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.length` will be `undefined` and you're calling the response object `obj` not `data`. What you'll get back from PHP is this;

```
{
    "FirstName": 1,
    "Surname": 2,
    "Age": 3
}
```

To cater for this, update your JS to:

```
// if (obj.length>0){   remove this
   jQuery("input.fname").val(obj.FirstName); 
   jQuery("input.sname").val(obj.Surname); 
   jQuery("input.age").val(obj.Age); 
// }  and this...
```

Note the case-sensitivity of JavaScript.

Additionally, as pointed out by Nicola Peluchetti, you should be checking for `$_GET['num']` rather than `$_GET['id']`.

You should also have more protection against SQL injection attacks. Escape your input with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) at least:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . '"';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's here

```
$id = $_GET['num'];
```

instead of

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

because your querystring should be something like

```
find.php?num=3
```

end then looking better at your code the error should be

```
   jQuery("input.fname").val(obj.FirstName); 
   jQuery("input.sname").val(obj.Surname); 
   jQuery("input.age").val(obj.Age);
```

without `obj.length` as stated correctly in anothe ranswer

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{num:id}` with `{id:id}`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout below code with your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#go").click(function() {
        var id=$("#myid").val();
        $.getJSON('http://localhost/test/test/json_action.php',{num:id},function(obj){
            //alert(obj.toSource());
           $("input.fname").val(obj.FirstName); 
           $("input.sname").val(obj.Surname); 
           $("input.age").val(obj.Age); 

         });
     });
});
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="myid" id="myid" value="2" />
<input type="button" value="Go" id="go" />
<input type="text" class="fname" />
<input type="text" class="sname" />
<input type="text" class="age" />
```

json_action.php

```
$result = array('FirstName' => 1, 'Surname' => 2, 'Age' => 3);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Above is almost same as your code and i can fill up value by clicking go button. And you are getting this error ' an undefined index error -> Notice: Undefined index: num in *:******************\website\find.php on line 10 ' cause your are not passing id in your query. By the way i cant see any use of query so i have eliminated in my json_action.php file. Hope this will help you.

Comment: also included alert for your reference.

Comment: I will edit my question with the new code, still not working unfortunately